# slickgrid showing object instead of values

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js, slickgrid

I am following example of [Slickgrid](http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example1-simple.html)

I am loading data using ajax into observable array

```
$.ajax({
    url: "../Service/Data",
    type: "PUT",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    processData: false,
    data: JSON.stringify(Id),
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        alert(errorThrown);
    },
    success: function (allData) {
        var mappedData= $.map(allData, function (item) {

            return new TableData(item);
        });
        self.MyArray(mappedData);
    }
});
```

Then in my view model is do this

```
grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", self.MyArray(), columns, options);
```

In my view i do as below

```
 <div id="myGrid" style="width:300px;height:420px;"></div>
```

But i get below output in my grid. Its not showing data but object

[image]

What can be wrong here?

**Update1**

here is my column definition

```
var columns = [
      { id: "title", name: "Title", field: "title" },
      { id: "duration", name: "Duration", field: "duration" },
      { id: "percent", name: "% Complete", field: "percent" }

    ];

    var options = {
        enableCellNavigation: true,
        enableColumnReorder: false
    };
```

THis is how my obs array in actual code looks like

[image]

**Update 2**
This is my TableData

```
  function TableData(data) {

        this.id= ko.observable(data.id);
        this.duration= ko.observable(data.duration);
        this.percent= ko.observable(data.percent);
    }
```

I get json data from server

Comment: what does self.MyArray() return ?

Comment: @Gaetano self.MyArray() returns array of data

Comment: @Tanner when i do the way you say i get error function expected

Comment: @Gaetano i get array with Method and prototype. Inside this method i have my columns. I dont know what kind of object it is called. May be thats the reason?

Comment: That is probably the reason why - Can you show me the definition of MyArray()

Comment: @Gaetano MyArray is observableArray.

Comment: @Gaetano i have added image in my question which shows my array

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, and you don't show what the format of the JSON that comes back from ../Service/Data actually is but, have you tried just writing the returned JSON data into MyArray directly?

```
success: function (allData) {
    self.MyArray = allData;
}
```

Comment: What I mean is if you are passing back an JSON array back from the ajax call and the properties in the JSON match 1:1 with the columns you have in your grid definition, why not pass it directly to the grid?  BTW, Column is configured to expect a property of 'title' and your taking data.id and writing it into a property of id (did you want to do that?).

Comment: have you tried using the code I gave above or any of the knockout utility functions such as ko.mapping.fromJS(allData, {}, MyArray); - see http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html for more information on the mapping options

Comment: I tried using your code and i get javascript runtime error Object doesnt support this action

Comment: Does slickGrid support data held in ko.observable's or does it expect the daat to be JSON or a just in a plain old JS array?.  If it's the later - just loop through allData and push each item into an array instead